# request.data in DRF vs request.body in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django REST framework introduces a Request object that extends the regular HttpRequest, this new object type has `request.data` to access JSON data for 'POST', 'PUT' and 'PATCH' requests.

However, I can get the same data by accessing request.body parameter which was part of original Django HttpRequest type object.

One difference which I see is that request.data can be accessed only one time. This restriction doesnt apply to request.body.

My question is what are the differences between the two. What is preferred and what is the reason DRF provides an alternative way of doing same thing when `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

UPDATE: Limiting the usecase where body is always of type JSON. Never XML/ image or conventional form data. What are pros/cons of each?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should use `request.data`. It's more flexible, covers more use cases and it can be accessed as many times as needed. Quoting the docs:

Aboout [`request.data`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects)

> REST framework introduces a Request object that extends the regular
> HttpRequest, and provides more flexible request parsing. The core
> functionality of the Request object is the request.data attribute,
> which is similar to request.POST, but more useful for working with Web
> APIs.
>
> request.POST  # Only handles form data. Only works for 'POST' method.

> request.data  # Handles arbitrary data. Works for 'POST', 'PUT' and
> 'PATCH' methods.

About [`request.body`](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/request-response.html#django.http.HttpRequest.body)

> The raw HTTP request body as a byte string. This is useful for
> processing data in different ways than conventional HTML forms: binary
> images, XML payload etc. For processing conventional form data, use
> HttpRequest.POST.

So unless you want to handle binary images or XML payload, never use `request.body`, it'll only be a simple string containing, well, the body of the request. Always use `request.data` which'll be the fully parsed body (i.e. a Python `dict`) which is much more convenient to handle.

Comment: request.data doesnt seem to be available in middlewares.

Comment: `request.body` is also useful if you are using a hash to check the identity of the sender. The sender can generate a HMAC SHA256 digest using a shared secret (such as an API token or API key) and include that hash as a header. The receiver then needs to generate the same hash with the same secret and compare it to the header, but that requires the identical body string: `request.body`, otherwise the hash won't be the same. You would still use `request.data` though when actually accessing the individual fields.

Answer (score 8):

In `rest_framework.request.Request`

- `request.body` is bytes, which is always available, thus there is no limit in usage
- `request.data` is a "property" method and can raise an exception,
  but it gives you parsed data, which are more convenient

---

However, the world is not perfect and here is a case when `request.body` win

Consider this example:

If client send:
  `content-type: text/plain`

and your REST's endpoint doesn't accept `text/plain`

your server will return `415 Unsupported Media Type`
if you access `request.data`

But what if you know that `json.loads(request.body)` is correct json.
So you want to use that and only `request.body` allow that.

FYI: A described example is a message of AWS SNS notification sent by AWS to HTTP endpoint. AWS SNS works as a client here and of course, this case is a bug in their SNS.

---

Another example of benefits from `request.body` is a case when you have own custom parsing and you use own MIME format.