# TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str & status code 500

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, http-status-code-500

I'm building an e-commerce site using ReactJS and Django (using redux)
I'm trying to send a post request to my DB but I'm getting the following error:

> firstName = data['firstName'],
> TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
> [31/May/2022 16:56:55] "POST /api/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 63122

Here is my code:
**View.js**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def createCitizen(request):
    data = request.body
    citizens = Citizen.objects.create (
        firstName = data['firstName'],
        lastName = data['lastName'],
        dateOfBirth = data['dateOfBirth'],
        address = data['address'],
        City = data['City'],
        zipCode = data['zipCode'],
        cellular = data['cellular'],
        landLine = data['landLine'],
        hadCovid = data['hadCovid'],
        previousConditions = data['previousConditions']
    )
    serializer = CitizensSerializer(citizens, many=True)
    serializer.save()
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

The relevant part in **RegisterPage.js**

```
 const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(createCitizens({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      dateOfBirth,
      address,
      City,
      zipCode,
      cellular,
      landLine,
      hadCovid,
      previousConditions
    }))
  }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <Row>
              <h4>Please enter your information:</h4>
            </Row><br></br><Row className="mb-3">
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="firstName">
                  <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    placeholder="Enter first name"
                    required
                    value={firstName}
                    onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Group>
...
```

**citizenAction.js**

```
export const createCitizens = (citizens) => async (dispatch) => {

    try {
        dispatch({type: 'CITIZEN_CREATE_REQUEST'})

        const {data} = await axios.post('/api/create/', citizens)

        dispatch({
            type: 'CITIZEN_CREATE_SUCCESS',
             payload: data
            })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'CITIZEN_CREATE_FAIL', 
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message,
    })
    }
}
```

I fill in the form string but got this error, is anyone know what's the problem? and why I got error code 500?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show the  Model.py where Citizen model is defined

Comment: I think the problem would be where you defined the model , Check if the firstname field is defines with Model.textField , not Model.IntegerFiled

Comment: `data = request.body` did you mean to write `data = request.data`? `request.body` is a bytestring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [request.data in DRF vs request.body in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616309/request-data-in-drf-vs-request-body-in-django)

Comment: @AkashNO In my model I'm using: `firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I used `data = request.data` but i got `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'` and changing to `data=request.body` fixed it.

Comment: You are also missing an `@` before the `api_view(['POST'])` i.e. it should be `@api_view(['POST'])`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It was cut while copying.